# Windows stuck after login prompt in normal mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista

I was trying to upgrade from Windows Vista to Windows 7 yesterday, and uninstalled a few programs on the recommendation of the upgrade assistant.

Since then, the machine is behaving very strangely. After the password prompt, it just hangs and keeps on displaying the rotating pointer for hours. A few times, it went past and opened the desktop, but it was totally unresponsive.

I am able to use the machine perfectly fine in Safe mode. However, there are no restore points available.

:(

Any help regarding what can be done here? I do not want to do a clean install of Win7 since I will lose my data. Any way to figure out what is preventing Windows from behaving normally here?

Answer (score 2):

Boot in safe mode, and run [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)
Check the LogOn applications and your Services. Disable anything non essential... one by one until you find the troublesome culprit. Even AV, just keep it unplugged from the internet/network.